# Deployment failed in Tomcat server

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am trying to publish one page on tomcat server. But it fails at Deploying phase with error message

Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you get any exception before this message?

Comment: The error usually means that one or more jar files are missing. Did you follow the instructions in the installation manual?

Comment: Or a listener fails on startup.

Comment: Check the CD logs. Core and/or Deployer will tell you more. This usually means a jar missing or wrong configuration.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The error was due to wrong configuration in cd_deployer_config.xml. That I fixed. But now I am getting error at committing deployment phase. Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-44-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-44-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection

Answer (score 3):

Please also check password encryption in cd_storage_conf.xml: try without password encryption and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. The error was due to wrong configuration in cd_deployer_config.xml. That I fixed. But now I am getting error at committing deployment phase.

Error: 
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-44-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-44-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection

Comment: Cannot open connection indicates that your database (server/username/password) information is not correct in cd_storage_conf.xml.